# Using the AD9833 for a 2MHz square wave

Tags: dds

Will I be able to accuratley generate a 2MHz square wave using the [AD9833 (pdf data sheet)](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD9833.pdf) ? I know that as you approach the clock frequency on a DDS you get distorted output signals. I was just wondering whether this is a little to close and if anyone has any experiance with this?

I want to achieve a square wave at 2Mhz, I'd like it at around 3-5Vpp. I'm happy to use other signal generators, I'm not set on the AD9833 and I've been looking at the AD9850 but putting the sinewave through the comparator seems a very roundabout way of getting a square wave out...

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The AD9833 seems to be overkill for this application, as well as of questionable suitability for the reasons you outline here. You can buy 2MHz crystals and fast comparators. I would suggest you use those instead. It will also be easier to produce 5V pk.-pk. with this method.

Comment: What do you consider "accurate", an accurate frequency, shape of waveform, voltage ? All of these ? The AD9833 can also make a square wave as can the AD9850. But why do you (think you) need a DDS ? I can make a 5 V 2 MHz squarewave using an Arduino board for $2.

Answer (score 3):

It actually is not a roundabout method if you really think about it.

The analog multi-pole low-pass filtering kills the higher harmonics that would otherwise cause large jitter in the output. How could you possibly expect to get sub-clock width resolution in the output waveform without an analog step?

However, if you **just** need 2MHz, you can buy a crystal oscillator that directly generates the 2MHz (eg. Fox [FXO-HC736R-2](http://belfuse.com/pdfs/0845-2D1T-H5.pdf) ) or use a higher frequency such as 8MHz and divide it down with a couple flip-flops. The DDS comes in handy if you want to generate oddball and/or variable frequencies or even frequency sweeps with relatively fine resolution.

Another approach is to use a reference frequency and a PLL such as a [74HC4046](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd74hc4046a.pdf), by dividing down the output frequency before feedback you can generate various frequencies.

Answer (score 1):

The MSB is directly available at the Vout pin by setting the OPBITEN (D5) control bit to 1, which directly generates a square wave.  Offsets would be generated by analog post-processing.